# Repositories should always return objects?

Tags: php, zend-framework, repository-pattern, doctrine-orm

This question got me today, my repositories should always return full objects? They can not return partial data (in an array for example)?

For example, I have the method `getUserFriends(User $user)` inside my repository `Friends`, in this method I execute the following DQL:

`$dql = 'SELECT userFriend FROM Entities\User\Friend f JOIN f.friend userFriend WHERE f.user = ?0';`

But this way I'm returning the users entities, containing all the properties, the generated SQL is a SELECT of all fields from the User table. But let's say I just need the id and the name of the user friends, there would be more interesting (and quick) get just these values?

`$dql = 'SELECT userFriend.id, userFriend.name FROM Entities\User\Friend f JOIN f.friend userFriend WHERE f.user = ?0';`

These methods are executed in my service class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a database perspective, performance will not be that much affected by the number of fields, unless the number of rows to return is really huge (millions of rows, probably) : the hardest part for the db is to make the joints, and build the resultset from the tables.

From a php perspective, that depends on multiple factors, like the complexity and the number of objects created.

I would take the problem differently : I would profile and stress-test my code in order to see if performance is an issue or not, and decide to refactor only if needed (switching from doctrine to a hand-made model is time consuming, will the performance gain be worth it ?)

EDIT : and to answer your initial question : fetching complete objects will lead to easier caching if needed, and better data encapsulation. I would keep these until they represent a big performance issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use partial keyword in your DQL : http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/partial-objects.html?highlight=partial

But only do that if your app has performance issues.